# Android: FBO to Bitmap. Scrambled result with NPOT image sizes on some devices

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es-2.0

Honestly, I don't like to ask things this way, but I have no clue about this one!

Have you seen this before??

[image]

It can be seen that the image is scrambled following some defined pattern. This happens only in some (low end) devices, with Non Power of two images (FBO). It works well on other devices.

What I do, is to load an Android Bitmap to a FBO (works OK, as it shows ok on the screen). I do some editing (I paste a sticker, which in the image seems to be in the right place), and finally save the FBO into a Bitmap again. It works ok for a 512x512 FBO (the FBO has the image size), but no for that one (507x800).

Any Ideas??? I don't post code because I have no clue, please tell me and I'll add it.

This is the GL call to retrieve info from FBO

```
public Buffer toPixelBuffer(){
        final int w = this.getWidth(); //colorTexture width 
        final int h = this.getHeight();
        final ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtils.newByteBuffer(w*h * 4);
        Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL10.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(0,0, w, h, GL20.GL_RGBA, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
        pixels.clear();
        return pixels;
    }
```

I also don't have a buggy device with me to test right now :(

Thank you!

Comment: Are you guaranteed that your FBO texture is bound (not the FBO itself, the texture) when you execute the glPixelStorei() command?

Comment: I do call the glFrameBufferTexture2D after glBindFrameBuffer, but wouldn't that produce a black screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I experienced this on Galaxy Ace, Galaxy Y, and some other devices.

After lot of testing I did found out that it wasn't even required POT textures, so keeping the texture size with a 64 pixel increment made the trick. So lets say if I have a 122x53 texture, I need to convert it to 128x64. An so on.

Next is the function I use to get a valid texture dimension. Call it for both Width and Height.

```
/**
 * Some GPUs such as the "VideoCore IV HW" on the Samsung Galaxy Ace
 * require texture (FBO) sizes to be in '64' increments (WTF!!!!)
 * 
 * @param dimension
 *            Base dimension to calculate
 * @return Resolved 64 dimension
 */
public static int calculate64Dimension(final int dimension)
{
    return  (((dimension - 1) >> 6) << 6) + 64;
}
```

Comment: Hey, a bit late but thanks!! I'd never imagine! +1 because of the ''64' increments (WTF!!!!)' comment :D. I ended up using NPOT textures, quite a memory waste. I'm sure you don't need a for statement to calculate a 64 dimension but that's ok --E.g. (((dimension -1)>>6) << 6) +64;! But that's just a detail. Thank you.Regards

Comment: Thanks for the simplified 1 liner code. I've updated the answer as it might be of use to other developers.

Comment: FWIW: `return (dimension + 63) & ~63;`